# flask_login @login_required continues to redirect me to login page after login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        """
        flash('Login requested for user {}, remember_me={}'.format(
            form.username.data, form.remember_me.data))
        """
        # Checks if user name and password-hash are the same in the db (Log in). Else it will show error message
        if user_name_exist(form.username.data) and get_password(form.username.data) == \
                md5(form.password.data.encode()).hexdigest():
            user = User.query.get(form.username.data)
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
            flash(current_user.is_authenticated)
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            form.showerror.text = "Password or User Name Incorrect"
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

I confirm that the user is logged in by using the current_user.is_authenticated function, which is returning True. But i still cannot get to pages that i have the @login_required on them. What am I doing wrong?

```
@app.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    form = ShowRoomsForm()
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', form=form)
```

EDIT: (Code for login manager)

```
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
```

I was able to fix this.
The problem was my user loader function was getting the user through the user name and not id. i changed it to being by id and the problem was solved
Here is the fix:

```
@login.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
    if user:
        return user
    return None
```

Comment: first you can remove `@login_required` and then check inside `index()` if `current_user.is_authenticated` gives `True` in this moment. Maybe in other code you didn't set it correctly. Browser need to keep this information in cookies.

Comment: can you also include the code you used to set up the login manager for your flask app?

Comment: @RyanBaker I added the login manager

Comment: @furas I did what you said and i noticed that on the index page i get False do you have any idea what i can do to fix this?

Comment: where are you getting login_required decorator from, can you include the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this. The problem was my user loader function was getting the user through the user name and not id. i changed it to being by id and the problem was solved Here is the fix:

```
@login.user_loader
def user_loader(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
    if user:
        return user
    return None
```